# Do the alternate floors permenantly replace the originals?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Easy question, do the alternate floors (AKA enviornments) permenantly replace the orignal floors? Like, when I beat all the bosses in the Basement and the Cellar starts spawning, will I ever get to play the Basement again or will it always be Cellar now? (the same for Caves / Catacombs, Depths / Necropolis, Womb / Utero, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  You have a random chance of getting the alternate floor once you've unlocked it.

I think the chances of getting the regular floor are higher than the chance of getting an alternative floor.

Incidentally, floor 1 and floor 2 could be one alternate and one regular unless you get an XL floor.

Comment: Additionally, the chances of getting an alternative floor are supposedly higher if you play on hardmode.

Comment: @No.7892142 That would make sense, since the alternate floors tend to have more difficult enemies.

Comment: The [wiki](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Hard_mode), which cannot always be trusted, supports this: